# English translation of a book of J.L. Lions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, mathematical-french

Anyone knows if there is an english translation of the book

J.L. Lions, Quelques Méthodes de Résolution des Problémes aux Limites Non Linéaires, Dunod,
Paris, 1969

?

Or do someone at least know an englisch reference with similar content?

Comment: Why don't you attempt to read it in French ? Mathematics written in French are easy to follow (a good half of the vocabulary is the same or almost the same as in English). I wouldn't say that for Hungarian, with due respect to this language.

Comment: Well, it's still more time-consuming than reading it in a familiar language. unfortunately I don't speak French.

Comment: @MackeyTopology: It’s worth the effort and, with all due respect to the language, mathematics in French is relatively easier than literary French.